# Wrong Password when using system-installed TOR with Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, linux

I am using Fedora linux with system installed TOR and Tor Browser 7.0.1.
I first did

```
export TOR_CONTROL_PASSWD='"secret"'
```

and edited /etc/tor/torrc to the new password by adding the line

```
HashedControlPassword 16:C00D0BBA106618AF6014B12230735F6BE934D897193B76D6029CBE68E6
```

that was generated with `tor --hash-password secret`, then I restarted TOR.

Using Netcat, doing `nc 127.0.0.1 9051`

```
authenticate "secret"
250 OK
```

this means the password is correctly set to `secret`.

But when I try launching TOR Browser in the same terminal where I exported the variable with the password I am unable to use the TOR Button which complains that TOR is not running. (I set `extensions.torlauncher.control_port` to the correct port, `9051`)(By default, Tor Browser uses `secret` as password)

Looking at the tor logs with `journactl -fu tor` it shows the following:

```
fedora Tor[16957]: New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
fedora Tor[16957]: Bad password or authentication cookie on controller.
fedora Tor[16957]: New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
fedora Tor[16957]: Bad password or authentication cookie on controller.
```

My  torrc is this:

```
ControlSocket /run/tor/control
ControlSocketsGroupWritable 1
CookieAuthentication 1
CookieAuthFile /run/tor/control.authcookie
CookieAuthFileGroupReadable 1
ControlPort 9051
HashedControlPassword 16:C00D0BBA106618AF6014B12230735F6BE934D897193B76D6029CBE68E6
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does `nc 127.0.0.1 9051 <<< "PROTOCOLINFO"` give you?

Comment: The `"` at `export TOR_CONTROL_PASSWD='"secret"'` seem unnecessary.

Comment: It needs to be kept in double quotes, that's how I'd expect it to look. Otherwise it's interpreted as a cookie by the control port (since it'd be sent verbatim without the quotes).

Comment: @canonizingironize
`250-PROTOCOLINFO 1
250-AUTH METHODS=COOKIE,SAFECOOKIE,HASHEDPASSWORD COOKIEFILE="/run/tor/control.authcookie"
250-VERSION Tor="0.2.9.10"
250 OK`

Answer (score -1):

Tor Browser sets its own hashed control password on the command-line, overriding the torrc. You can set the TOR_CONTROL_PASSWD environmental variable instead:
https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TorBrowserBundleSAQ

The Tor manual might also be helpful:
https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en